# How do I run my GStreamer pipeline with 'nvcamerasrc' in my docker container (on a TX2 board) without 'ERROR: Connecting to camera_daemon failed'?

Tags: docker, gstreamer, nvidia, daemon

The docker container was created with the --privileged flag and has the /dev, /proc and /sys folders mounted from the host Tegra TX2 board, so the docker container has the 'nvhost...' devices such as 'nvhost-gpu'.

However when I run the GStreamer pipeline which uses the 'nvcamerasrc' element I get 'Connecting to camera_daemon failed'.

```
ERROR nvcamerasrc gstnvcamerasrc.cpp:2411:gst_nvcamera_socket_connect:<camera_src> Connecting to camera_daemon failed
```

I manually copied the actual 'nvcamera-daemon' and 'nvcamera-daemon.service' files from usr/sbin and etc/systemd/system on the host to the same places in the container but this has not made a difference.

So I'm just trying to use the nvcamera-daemon service (the nvcamerasrc requires this) from a docker container on the TX2 board rather than directly on the board. Has anyone had success with Tegra-docker https://github.com/Technica-Corporation/Tegra-Docker or another method of doing this, perhaps that doesn't require Cuda?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
`sudo docker run --net=host --runtime nvidia --rm --ipc=host -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/ -v /tmp/argus_socket:/tmp/argus_socket --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -it nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.3.1`
*note: the version is .3 now*  [src](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1070578/jetson-nano/jetpack-4-3-csi-camera-support-from-within-containers/post/5423691/#5423691)

if you encounter EGL connection error try : `unset DISPLAY` on docker
(which sounds contradictory to the aforementionned post like [on this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1062981/deepstream-sdk/how-do-i-turn-egl-display-off-/post/5401411/#5401411))